# IPC between two iOS apps

Tags: ios, ipc, ios-universal-links

I need to establish IPC between 2 iOS apps where app2 asks if data is present in app1. The main goal is to call a function inside app2, which then gets a (in this case BOOL) response from app1.

Is that possible? Can I use UniversalLinks for that? How can i achieve this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: App2 would need to open app1 using a URL containing a URL scheme registered by app1. App1 would then need to open app2 using apps2's URL scheme, passing the bool in the URL string.

Comment: I do not intend to open app1, i will just ask it for information without opening it, like AIDL bound services in Android. So i think App Groups with shared NSUserDefaults is the way to go in iOS, am I right?

Comment: Yes, if both apps are from the same developer then you can share files and user defaults but that isn't IPC; App1 isn't active, it has just previously stored some data where app2 can read it.

Comment: I know, but is there a way to establish true IPC on iOS?

Comment: No, there is not.if app2 is running then generally app1 is suspended. You can’t force app1 to run in the background from app2.